# Sql compare TimeStamp with normal date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How can i compare timeStamp date with normal date 
SQL:

```
select * from mg_customers_conversation where timecreated>='2014-09-09'
```

This will give me 0 values as its comparing with timeStamp

Note :column timecreated is an `timestamp`

column timecreated 2012-12-01 00:00:00

And can any one Explain me how can i do this using Date_format,`STR_TO_DATE` methods in SQL

Comment: you've tagged this as mysql and sql-server...which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
select * from mg_customers_conversation where DATE_FORMAT(timecreated,'%Y-%m-%d')>='2014-09-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL, the `timestamp` data type has nothing to do with date or time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx