# Compare timestamp with date in sql

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi I am storing `date_added` with a timestamp in the database .

Now a user wants to see particular transactions on a particular day so he enters the date which is in `2015-05-20` format and the one stored in table is `2015-05-20 13:01:01` format. 
 How can I fetch rows by only considering the date part in the table and not the time. 
I have tried google and found `TO_CHAR` which didn't work for me. Also [found this link on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910123/sql-compare-timestamp-with-normal-date) but didn't work for me.

This is my sql which I get when I die it in the model

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_return` r 
LEFT JOIN oc_return_status rs 
ON (r.return_status_id = rs.return_status_id) 
WHERE r.organization_id = '4' 
AND DATE(r.date_added) = DATE(2015-05-06) 
ORDER BY r.return_id DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

I manipulated the query by removing the `DATE()` and adding colons, removing them. Also when I there is an entry of it in the table and even when I remove organization_id from the query it shows up

Wild card too didn't work for me. I tried converting to some other format but that too didn't work. I just want that when I fire Query by date it should only check the date part in table and ignore the time part. Please help. Thanks in advance for suggestions/help.

Comment: You don't need to do any reformatting - your date is already in Y-m-d format; just do a `WHERE date >= :date` type thing...

Comment: the `:` is intentional ? @CD001

Comment: yes - it's just representing a placeholder as you'd use with a bound parameter; it's essentially your `$date` string

Comment: And sorry I can't use `>=` I just want the very day irrespective of time

Comment: Have you tried with DATE_FORMAT(date_added,'%Y:%m:%d') in where clause?

Comment: yes @RakeshShewale I did.. it just gave a empty set :-(

Comment: I have tried all the possible combinations I found but either improper use or empty result set. I will be off the hook. Please leave your suggestions so that  i can see it later. Thank you

Comment: I would try this DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_added`), '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @PreetiMaurya if the below answer doesn't work, then your date isn't in the Y-m-d format or something else is wrong.  Show your code and your debugging techniques.

Comment: DevLakshman's answer below then is totally correct for MySQL if you only want the given day... otherwise you could, using **2015-05-20** as an example, do something like `WHERE date >= '2015-05-20' AND date < '2015-05-21'` but that *shouldn't* be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

use `DATE(TIMESTAMP_DATABASE)` your sql query. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_NAME WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_DATABASE)='$DATE_USER'
```

Comment: already used this. didn't work for me. this came into my mind the very first minute

Comment: This will not use indexes on date field, if there are any. Better solution would be to fetch records like `... date_field BETWEEN '$date 00:00:00' AND '$date 23:59:59'` where variable `$date` has date in format `Y-m-d`.